# How to detect on which layer is something located

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, layer

I would like to know how to detect on which layer is an instance located.For example i put a circle named bob on the first layer and a square named test on the second layer. In actionscript, can i detect on which layer is test.

I want to use this because in my game i will put all the non solid objects on the first layer and all the solid objects on the second layer and i want to detect in actionscript which instances are located in which layers

Comment: I believe in ActionScript there's no concept of layers from the Flash authoring tool, and the various layers are simply interpreted by the code as the ordering of the stage's children. I haven't used the Flash authoring tool in a long time however so I don't remember.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In actionscript 3 there is no such thing as layers. It is only a convenience for Flash IDE users to group certain elements until actual SWF compiling occurs. At compile time all the objects are added to the `stage` according to the hierarchy of the layers but they all belong to the same `stage` object with different `childIndex` properties.
To use the concept of layers in actionscript 3, you should add your solid objects to a `Sprite` or `MovieClip` and then check, whether the instance in question is belonging to solid object or not, like this:

```
var solidContainer:Sprite = new Sprite();
this.addChild(solidContainer);
solidContainer.addChild(someSolidObject);

var nonSolidContainer:Sprite = new Sprite();
this.addChild(nonSolidContainer);
nonSolidContainer.addChild(someNonSolidObject);

function isSolid(object:DisplayObject):Boolean {
  if (solidContainer.contains(object)) {
    return true;
  } else  {
    return false;
  }
}

isSolid(someNonSolidObject); // returns false
```